# Mutating state is considered bad practcice, but how do I avoid mutating state when i submit my form?

Tags: reactjs, state, javascript-objects

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ContactForm = () => {

    const [newContact, setNewContact] = useState({})

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [number, setNumber] = useState('')

    const nameInput = e => {
        let newName = e.target.value
        setName(newName)
    }
    const numberInput = e => {
        let newNumber = e.target.value
        setNumber(newNumber)
    }

    const contactFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const contactObject = {
            name: name,
            number: number
        }
        setNewContact({ ...newContact, name: contactObject.name, number: contactObject.number })
        setName('')
        setNumber('')
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form htmlFor="contacForm" onSubmit={contactFormSubmit}>
                <h2>add contact</h2>
                <div>
                    <label>name</label>
                    <input htmlFor="name" id="name" name="contact_name" value={name} onChange={nameInput} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>number</label>
                    <input htmlFor="number" id="number" name="contact_number" value={number} onChange={numberInput} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

In this case, I want to create a `contact` which is an object, initially my state is an empty object

```js
    const [newContact, setNewContact] = useState({})
```

I'm using two input fields for `name` and `number` and then my `onSubmit` event handler is this

```js
   const contactFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()

        const contactObject = {
            name: name,
            number: number
        }
        setNewContact({ ...newContact, name: contactObject.name, number: contactObject.number })
        setName('')
        setNumber('')
    }
```

In react mutating the state is considered a bad practice, I'm wondering if this way of setting my `newContact` is going to mutate the state, if so how do I avoid it?

Is it a rule of thumb that, *onSubmit the data that I send will mutate the state*?
Is what I'm doing here considered mutating state?

Comment: Mutating state directly is bad practice, changing state using ```setState``` or ```setX``` for hooks is the proper way to change state. State has to be changed in most applications, but doing it outside of React's data flow creates problems as React cannot track the changes. This code looks fine to me.

Comment: use redux for state management

Comment: Im not familiar with redux, will being a beginner in react make it difficult to learn redux?

Comment: I disagree with @yannicuLar, you don't need redux for a simple form like this. Using `setState` should be fine like @Chris B. said

Answer (score 1):

I believe you misunderstood what mutating state means. What you are doing is just right, because you are **creating a new object every time**.

```
setNewContact({ *I am a new object who is gonna replace the old one* })
```

It would be **mutating state** if you modified the current instance of the state. Instead of using "setNewContact" you go like:

```
newContact.name = contactObjeject.name
newContact.number= contactObjeject.number
```

Comment: so using the setter provided by useState is the right way?